# Can't remove "optional" from String in Swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, option-type

I have tried all the tips and codes here to exclude the "optional" from string (print an label) but none worked. I understood what should fix it but i just can't make it works. Here is my code and thanks.

```
    func UsuarioLogado(){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (FIRauth, usuario) in

            if let usuariolog = usuario {
            print("usuario logado!!!" + String(describing: usuariolog.email))
                self.txtUsuarioLogado.text = String(describing: "Avaliador logado: \(usuariolog.email)")
            }else{
                print("usuario nao esta logado")
                self.txtUsuarioLogado!.text = String(describing: "Nenhum avaliador logado")
            }
        })
}
```

But I have this:

```
usuario logado!!!Optional("abobora@generico.com")
```

Comment: `if let usuario = usuario, let email = usuario.email { print(email)` or simply `if let email = usuario?.email { print(email)`

Comment: print(someOptional!)

Comment: Thank you very much @LeoDabus